# Don't load undo file if it's too large in Vim 7.3+

Tags: vim, undo

I just copied a massive amount of text (on the order of millions of lines, I think) into a Vim register, opened a new file, pasted, and then proceeded to edit the new copy of the excerpt. Vim was reasonably quick throughout the whole process; it was a nice showcase of the power of Vim.

....except that I'm using the persistent undo feature. So after a little bit of time spent editing, I noticed that my Vim session was taking up an enormous amount of memory (about 3x as much as my Chrome session, which is a lot by Vim standards). At first I thought it was because my massive copy was still in one of the registers, but when I went to edit `.viminfo`, the longest register value was about 20 lines. I tried restarting Vim a few times, but each time it loaded that particular file, it would hang for an unacceptable amount of time (again, by Vim standards).

...So I realized that I needed to delete my undo file for the problematic file. This solved my immediate problem, but I'd like to avoid encountering it again. So I would like an autocmd in my VimRC that will do the following:

- Upon loading a file, check the size of the corresponding undo file (if it exists)
- If the undo file is larger than `x Mb` (or whatever size), do one of the following:

  - Delete it
  - Keeping only the most recent changes, delete changes until the file is a reasonable size (this would be the preferred behavior)

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Comment: Only tangentially related, but here's a shout-out to a pretty cool script (not mine, but I ran it as soon as I found it) that does something Vim should really have some kind of built-in capability for: https://github.com/doy/conf/blob/master/bin/clean-vim-undo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `undo-persistence`:

```
The 'undofile' option is checked after writing a file, before the BufWritePost
autocommands.  If you want to control what files to write undo information
for, you can use a BufWritePre autocommand: >
    au BufWritePre /tmp/* setlocal noundofile
```

I was going to suggest that you decide, before writing the undo file, how big it is going to be, then decide whether to set `'undofile'`.  It is probably easier to let vim write the file, then use a `BufWritePost` autocommand to check the size of the newly written file and, if it is too big, delete it.

Answer (score 2):

The [LargeFile - Edit large files quickly](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506) plugin detects large files and tweaks many options to accommodate this better. It also turns `'undolevels'` off to avoid that large increase in memory you've seen.

Comment: Really ought to have been using this anyway--thanks for the suggestion. I'm accepting the other answer just because it's more specific to the particular problem I had, but +1 to yours as well.